# Declared type of the inotify_event buffer

Tags: c, linux, language-lawyer, inotify

Here is a fragment of the example provided in the [`man inotify(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html):

```
static void handle_events(int fd, int *wd, int argc, char* argv[]){

    //...

    char buf[4096]
      __attribute__ ((aligned(__alignof__(struct inotify_event))));
    const struct inotify_event *event;

    //...

    ssize_t len;
    char *ptr;

    //...

    len = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf);

    //...

    for (ptr = buf; ptr < buf + len;
          ptr += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + event->len) {
       event = (const struct inotify_event *) ptr;  <---- CASTING HERE

    //...other code accessing struct inotify_event *event omitted
    }
}
```

The thing I was confused by is that we have object with declared type `char[4096]` but we use to access it value via an lvalue of type `struct inotify_event`.

Applying `6.5(p7)`:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types:88)
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object

The Standard allows converting ***a pointer*** to char to ***a pointer*** to any other object type (in this case `struct inotify_event`).

But to access the stored value we need to have the effective type to be compatible with the lvalue we use to access the object.

The same alignment requirements of two object types does not imply their compatibility (as far as I can tell).

Why is the code conforming? What did I miss?

Comment: "Why is the code conforming?" - it isn't.

Comment: However, you can replace `buf` with a buffer that is allocated with `aligned_alloc` and the resulting code is conforming.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Why isn't simple `malloc` enough? The `malloc`ed object has no declared type so its effective type is determined by an `lvalue` used to access.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala And besides if the code is not conforming is it safe to use it? As far as I can tell it is not neccesary be portable even across different gcc version.

Comment: well, `malloc` should be sufficient. If you want to control the alignment, then `aligned_alloc`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala So we cannot allocate a buffer for `struct inotify_event`s on the stack conformingly since the `struct inotify_event` have variable length array and cannot be used as a type of arrays.

Comment: No. Not that you'd really want that either...